# Присоединительные члены предложения

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены, члены-предложения

Имеем следующие предложения:

1. Я вам, товарищи, об этом расскажу, **но потом.**
2. Они сидела на стуле и наслаждалась вином, **но из двух бокалов.**
3. Он пришел на встречу, **но один**, и через непродолжительное время ушел.

Какую роль играют выделенные фрагменты? Я склоняюсь к тому, что это присоединительные члены предложения.

Они содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. В приведенных примерах выделенные фразы действительно содержат доп. замечания.

Примеры из справочника Розенталя:

1. Отец мой очень любил всякие воды, особенно ключевые.
2. Об этом газеты уже сообщали, и не раз.
3. Напишите заявление, да поскорее.

Вроде бы никакими неполными предложениями по типу *Широкие тени ходят по равнине, как облака [ходят, плавают] по небу. - неполное придаточное* здесь не пахнет.

Да и явно они не являются частью однородных членов, как, например, здесь: Они ждали  долго, но терпеливо.

Верны ли мои догадки? (Сомнение посеяло отсутствие союза "но" в справочнике).

Answer (score 1):

**Верны ли мои догадки? (Сомнение посеяло отсутствие союза "но" в справочнике).**

Согласен с Вами.
В некоторых источниках упоминается союз НО в качестве присоединительного. Например, в книге Н. Киреевой "Грамматический метод обучения русскому правописанию. Книга 2" сказано:

> Присоединительные члены с союзной связью присоединяются с помощью
>   особых слов, в роли которых могут выступать:
>   ...
>   Б) другие союзы в
>   значении присоединительных: ДА, И, ИЛИ, **НО**;

Также Вам может быть полезна [эта ссылка](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/analiz-opredeleniy-soyuzov-a-no-and-but-i-ih-sinonimov-dannyh-v-sovremennyh-slovaryah).

Comment: А в подобных конструкциях: Если я и приеду, то только через часа два. Если я и буду готовить, то только салаты и закуску. Союз "если" указывает на придаточное, значит, конструкция "то только через час" находится в главном, а из него никаких вопросов задать нельзя. Возможно, неполное, но если вставить "пропущенное", то получится плохо. Пример неполного, где это очевидно: Когда ты приедешь? Если поеду сейчас, то [приеду] через два часа.

Comment: Придаточные условия относятся ко всему главному предложению и отвечают на вопрос "*при каком условии?*". Задавайте, пожалуйста, вопросы на форуме, тогда выше шансы получить хороший ответ (или вообще ответ).

Comment: Главное все же выражено неполным?